# Как сделать кастомный CheckBox для TextView?

Tags: android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли использовать RadioCheck чтобы сделать такое?

Или в Android есть какой то спец View для такого?

Можете подсказать?

Comment: кастомизированный [RadioGroup](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/radiobutton.php) для этого используется. Ничего более специализированого в SDK нет

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно убрать у `RadioButton` свойство `button` в `xml` разметке, создать drawable xml, состоящий из двух состояний, checked=true/false. Также создать color состоящий из двух состояний, checked=true/false.

Разделы в помощь: `StateList` и `Shape Drawable`

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html